# ie 8 adds unnecessary top and bottom padding

Tags: css

ie 8 is adding unnecessary padding to a div. I cannot see any unusual styling here. Can somebody help ?

[image]

**Html**

The div highlighed in blue is the one in context.

[image]

```
.block {
    clear: both;
}

.inline {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    padding: 0;
}

div.content {
    padding: 0 18px 0 0;
}
```

Here is the html code that will reproduce this issue. Sorry about the length. But if you copy this to a html file and open it in ie8, you'll be able to reproduce it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

<style>
    .block {
        clear: both;
    }

    div.block .inline:last-child {
        float: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    div.content-root {
        padding: 0 0 0 18px;
    }

    .inline {
        float: left;
        clear: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    div.content.input-container {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    div.content {
        padding: 0 18px 0 0;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="contentPane" style="background-color: transparent; display: block;">

    <form>
      <div class="block content-root">
        <div class="block">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="block">
              <div class="inline">
                <label>
                  <div class="block">
                    <div class="inline content input-container">
                      <input type="checkbox" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline">
                      <div class="block">
                        <div class="block">
                          <div class="inline" style="float: left;">
                            <div class="block content">
                              <p>
                                <span style="font-family: arial; font-size: 11pt;">C. </span>
                              </p>
                            </div>                                                 
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline">
                            <div class="inline">
                              <p><span>Correct</span></p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem

Comment: http://jsbin.com/#/uxuwoy/1/edit

Please use chrome, to open the example.

Comment: Thanks @Adrift, I see you deleted your answer. Would you post the link of the library you were talking about ?

Comment: Sure take a look at http://www.cssreset.com/ it has a few options for resets, though they all basically do the same thing - reset the default browser styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph tag has its own margin by default.

If you write

```
  <p style="margin:0px;">
```

the 'padding' above and below the word 'Correct' goes.